# importdata undefined within googlescript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet where I am tracking various asset prices including crypto.
The easiest way to get crypto prices is by importing from cryptocurrencies.cc:

```
=importdata("https://cryptoprices.cc/AION/");
```

However, now my spreadheet is full of references to the `cryptoprices.cc` website. If it ever goes down or changes domain, I would have to replace the URL everywhere in my sheet, which is quite uncontrolled. So I thought about making a wrapper function:

```
function cryptofinance(token) {
   return importdata("https://cryptoprices.cc/"+ token);
}
```

This returns an `#Error!` however: `ReferenceError: importdata is not defined (line 94).` I am assuming that you cannot call Google Sheet functions outside of the context of the Sheets cells, correct?

If not, what is the proper way to call `importdata` from within this function?
If yes, then what is the best alternative to retrieve the same information using javascript?

Answer (score 2):

You cant use importdata like a formula at this place.
first you need to get cell refernce then
you need to put formula inside the setvalue() function;

```
var currentCell = SpreadsheetApp.getCurrentCell(); // Select cell here 
currentCell.setValue('=importdata("https://cryptoprices.cc/"+ token)');
```

for select a range of cells you can use getRange() function

```
SpreadsheetApp.getRange(row,col).setValue('=importdata("https://cryptoprices.cc/AION/")');
```

change row, col with cells range.

Comment: This gives `Exception: You do not have permission to perform that action. (line 94).` Line 94 is `var currentCell = ...` Any thoughts?

Comment: you need to select the cell reference in currentCell 
like to access first cell of the current active sheet you can use

`var firstCell= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveSelection().getCell(1,1);`
and then you can setValue to firstcell